# Как заменить все названия ссылок в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка, в которой записан текст, и в нем вставлены ссылки таким образом:

```
<a  data-cknf="1" title="title" href="https://site.ru/" target="_blank">Название ссылки</a>
```

Ссылок может быть неопределенное количество. Мне нужно иметь возможность удалить тег , и оставить просто **Название ссылки**, но чтобы я мог еще манипулировать этим **Название ссылки**, к примеру установить кодировку именно для подписи ссылки, или заменить в ней некоторые слова.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `PHPQuery` и подобное, если вы хотите обработать уже имеющийся документ. Про кодировку правда не ясно о чем речь.

Comment: @teran кодировка это я как пример. нужно только средствами php. я имел ввиду чтобы я смогу все Названия ссылок преобразовать в нужный мне вид. то есть что бы получилось что-то вроде переменной, и сделав например так: `$perem = str_replace('Название', 'Мой текст', $allLinksName);` применились изменения ко всем названиям ссылок

Comment: @teran иными словами переименовать названия ссылок.