# Заменить названия ссылок

Tags: php

Есть ссылки

```
<a href="link">название ссылки</a>
<a href="link" title="подпись">название ссылки</a>
```

И подобные, атрибуты внутри  могут быть разные.

Мне же нужно найти и заменить только **название ссылки** всех ссылок которые есть в строке.

Желательно регуляркой.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `str_replace` - не подходит?

Comment: @Manitikyl главное чтобы можно было манипулировать с названиями ссылок

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заменить все названия ссылок в строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909111/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *нужно найти и заменить только название ссылки всех ссылок которые есть в строке*

Если нужен только поиск, тогда можно так:

```
$str = '<a href="link">название ссылки 1</a>
    <a href="link" title="подпись">название ссылки 2</a>';

preg_match_all('~<a[^>]*>(.+?)</a>~', $str, $arr);
var_dump( $arr[1] );
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'название ссылки 1'
  1 => string 'название ссылки 2'
```

---

Если поиск с заменой, тогда так:

```
$repl = 'Новое название ссылки';
$str = preg_replace('~(<a[^>]*>).+?(</a>)~', "$1{$repl}$2", $str);

var_dump( $str );
```

Результат:

```
<a href="link">Новое название ссылки</a>
<a href="link" title="подпись">Новое название ссылки</a>
```